# Finding the Probability of A=2B or 2A=B?

Tags: probability, statistics

Three Companies are bidding on a contract ... etc 
, Company (A) is twice as good as company (B), And Company (B) is three times as good as Company (C). What's the probability of each company winning the contract ..

I Know the process of the solution is making it as an equality and replacing with the value of Probability of (A) like that 
P(A)=2P(B)=6P(C) and P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1

But I want to make sure that it's P(A)=2P(B) not 2P(A)=P(B)
Because I learn english and confused about that part ..

Comment: And Company (C) is three times as good as Company (C)?

Comment: @bobbym sorry .. I Edited it .. Company (B) is three times as good as company (C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Company A is twice as good as Company B" could reasonably be interpreted to mean "Company A has twice as great a chance (= probability) of winning as Company B." So then P(A) is 2 times P(B), which is what you have said. You have the right approach.